# How to not print the day/month of a BibLaTeX reference?

Tags: biblatex

`BibLaTeX` seems to recommend<sup>1</sup> the yyyy-mm-dd format for dates such as:

```
 date = {1989-03-12}
```

I have no objection to this format *but* I would like to be able to cite without printing the month and the day. With old BibTeX date fields, it was easy:

```
month = mar,
year = {1989},
```

So, I used to add `\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{labelmonth}}` to my .tex files.

How can I get rid of the month and the day with this new (BibLaTeX) format?

PS: I precise **I cannot modify my .bib file.**

---

<sub>1: BibLaTeX manual says : "If there is no date field
in an entry, biblatex will also consider the fields year and month for backwards
compatibility with traditional BibTeX." (p.34) which indicates that fields `year` and `month` are obsoletes with BibLaTeX.</sub>

Comment: `\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{month} \AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{day}}` doesn't work?

Comment: @karlkoeller No (sorry)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a package option `date` for controlling this:

> date=year, short, long, terse, comp, iso8601  default: comp This option
>   controls the basic format of printed date specifications.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[date=year]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

with database entry

```
@Article{Author,
  author =   {Author, A.},
  title =    {A paper},
  journal =  {J. Jour.},
  date =     {1989-03-12}
}
```

yields

[image: Sample output]

Comment: Thanks! It is definitively the solution. For Debian users, you will have to wait the [2.8 version of BibLaTeX](http://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/RELEASE) or update manually.